# retrieve many data in the foreign key (one to many relationship) using native php

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, modal-dialog

So I have this kind of project to have post divided into several provinces.

I can show with modal the post but only 1 if there is 2 posts or more it will only show me 1 post. This is my code with PHP

```
foreach($table2 as $tab2){
              $link3=$_COOKIE[linkmenu].$tab2['id_news']."/"."geopark/".linkjudul($tab2['nm_news']);

                         $jdlpost=$tab2['nm_news'];
                         $despost=$tab2[description];

echo   "<div class=modal fade in' id='tc$ps3[id_news]> <div class=modal-dialog modal-lg> <div class='modal-content' style= 'margin-top: 100px;'>"
    <div class='modal-content' style= 'margin-top: 100px;'>"
                                        ."<div class='modal-header'>"
                                        ."<h5 class='modal-title' id='exampleModalLabel'>$jdlprovince</h5>
                                                        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'>
                                                        <span aria-hidden='true'>×</span>
                                                        </button>"
                                        ."</div>"
                                        ."<div class='modal-body'>"
                                        ."<div class='row'>"
                                        ."<div class='col-md-12'>"
                                        ."<div class='box-list'>"
                                        ."<div class='detailgeo dg3 tampil$ps3[id_news] active view view-tenth'>"
                                        ."<div class='coverhover'><div class='imgs' style='background-image:url(".$_COOKIE[config]."dynamic/200/imgnews/".$ps3[pict].")'> </div>
                                                               <div class='mask'>
                                                                   <a href='$link3' class='info' title='$jdlpost'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></a>
                                                               </div>
                                                           </div>"
                                        ."<div class='ise'><b><a href='$link3'>$jdlpost</a></b><i>".ucfirst(textlimit(rmSpecialChars(cleanHTML($despost)),180))."</i><div class='clear'></div><a href='$link3'class='remor' class='remor'>READ MORE <i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i></a></div>"
                                        ."</div>"
                                        ."</div>"
                                        ."</div>"
                                        ."</div>"
                                        ."</div>"
                                        ."</div>"
                                        ."</div>"
                                        ."</div>";
}
    }
```

Is there any code that I missing ? because I feel my code little bit wrong when I click it's only 1 post but from the inspect element it's retrieve all 3 post but with different div but with same id that retrieve tc2
[image]
The Idea is to make all post with same province in same modal so I need to merge this 3 posts div into 1 div with 3 post on it

Thanks

Comment: Your code have syntax errors. The second div you're trying to echo is missing `."` in front of it. I would recommend not echoing large chunks of HTML using PHP. Instead, end your PHP block with `?>`, output your HTML and then open it again after `<?php`. That would not only make your code _way_ easier to read and maintain, but IDE's will be able to syntax highlight the HTML as well, making it easier to find issues etc.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what do you mean

Comment: Line 7 in the posted code starts with`<div class='modal-content'` but should be `."<div class='modal-content'` since you're closing the string in the line above.

Comment: Actually, your code have _a lot_ of issues. For example, in: `<div class=modal fade in'`, you're missing the opening `'` for the class. There are plenty of issues like this. You're also missing quotes around array keys on multiple places, like  `$_COOKIE[linkmenu]` (should be `$_COOKIE['linkmenu']`) and so on.

Comment: ok thank you but it's not my problem I just want to get all this 3 post to show together in same modal

Comment: _"ok thank you but it's not my problem"_ - How did you come to that conclusion? If you output invalid HTML, you can't expect the output to be correct. Browsers don't know what you _mean_ to output, they only care about what you actually _are_ outputting. You should sort out _all_ of the issues in your code and see if it works better.

Comment: thanks magnus I changed my code with your advice :)

Comment: You're also missing a `</div>` in the end.

Comment: Thanks do you have an article for looping in same modal ? so I can learn from it

Comment: There's nothing special about looping data in a model. It's like looping anywhere else. Just make sure your HTML is correct.